# Camdesk doesn't work

Tags: python, webcam, screencast

I'm trying to use [camdesk](http://camdesk.sourceforge.net/) following this [OMG article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/camdesk-for-linux-adds-webcam-window-to-the-desktop), but camdesk isn't working and not sending any error messages.

I open it in terminal using:

```
./camdesk.py
```

A white square appears in the middle of my screen and nothing happens.
Then I launched it using:

```
python camdesk.py
```

And the same thing happened.

---

A last attempt, I tried:

```
python3 camdesk.py
```

It returned:

```
File "camdesk.py", line 12
  if event.keyval == gtk.keysms.Escape :
                                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

---

Here is a picture of what it looks like, a gray featureless box that has a slight dropshadow:
[image]

I recorded a video to show the problem.

[youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-3-C36i2mY&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: How about you describe us the problem. You know people don't want to sit couple of minutes viewing a video, also you must think about the users that use mobile.

Comment: @Braiam I know, but the problem is the camdesk is not showing any error, just not works, the only way I found to show is the video.

Comment: @Mateo the program fails to open, it is what i want to show! it is the problem, the program just open a white screen, and do nothing!

Comment: @Mateo the program is a python script, I run it on terminal. and like I said, it have no output. I only recorded the video because it.

Comment: please, if you don't want help, just leaves the question there for those who want to help.

Comment: I have added detailed description of what happened in your video, hope this fills in details for others so we can help.

Comment: Thak you @Mateo, i go add some details about the last try, the python3 not works because the script is writes to python2, i just tested to show it.

Comment: Hi @Mateo, anything happened with Fn+f1.

Comment: @Mateo on chrome opens the support tab, on ubuntu desktop anything happened.

Comment: @Mateo libs installed.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and I get two solutions:

1.- After running `./camdesk.py precione F1` and start working.

2.- If you want to execute the command, and you need to work immediately add the following line at the end of `init method: self.player.set_state` (`gst.STATE_PLAYING`)

stay follows.

```
def __ init__ (self): 
. 
. 
. 
bus.connect ("sync-message :: element", self.on_sync_message) 
self.player.set_state (gst.STATE_PLAYING)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's probably working fine. Put your cursor in the empty white box and press F1 to start the video. F2 to stop. F5 to adjust the size and behaviour.

I just read the README file that comes with it...